# changing class using hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5

what can i do to change style of `p` tag with class `zoom-p` to `display: none` and change `img` tag with class `zoom-img` to `display: block` on hover on the `.apartman` `div`?

```
            <div class="apartman">
                <div class="zoom">
                    <p style="display:block" class="zoom-p">Look Apartman</p>
                    <img style="display: none" class="zoom-img" src="images/plus.png">
                </div>
                <div class="apart-descr">
                    <p> 35.56m </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a couple of [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) selectors to your `.apartman` element:

```
.apartman:hover p.zoom-p{
    display: none;
}

.apartman:hover img.zoom-img{
    display: block;
}
```